# VB counter, get data from cell

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have problem that in this line that i dont get right value

```
<pre>strASCX = strASCX & "<br><font color=red> " & Sheets(1).Cells(i, j).Value & " </font>"<code>
```

this should choose the right date(right cell) in my excel calendar, but it doesnt. Here is part of picture of my calendar [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKJCw.png)
Where is word "value" with an "X" in cell next to it. I should get value from this cell. For example (look pricture) for cell B5 I should get "value3"

```
    For i = 3 To 33
    '---Rows---

    For j = 1 To 12
        '---Columns---

        For leto = year(Date) - 1 To year(Date) + 1
            mesec = (j * 3) - 1
            strASCX = strASCX & "if (e.Day.Date.Year == " & leto & "){if (e.Day.Date.Month == " & j & "){if (e.Day.Date.Day ==" & i - 2 & "){aLabel.Text ="""

                    If Sheets(1).Cells(2, mesec + 1) = leto Then
                         If Trim(Sheets(1).Cells(i, mesec)) <> vbNullString Then
                            status = UCase(Trim(Sheets(1).Cells(i, mesec + 1)))
                            Select Case status
                                Case Is = "X"
                                    strASCX = strASCX & "<br><font color=red> " & Sheets(1).Cells(i, j).Value & " </font>"
                            End Select
                         End If
                    End If

            strASCX = strASCX & """;" & "aLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(""#ccccc2""); e.Cell.Controls.Add(aLabel); }} }" & vbNewLine
        Next leto
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: What does it get? What is the value of mesec when it fails? Use the actual sheet name as well rather than position. And what is the value of i and j? Are they as expected? Step through with F8.

Comment: thanks, can u tell me how can i check values for i and j counter step by step by pressing F8

Comment: you could highlight each variable and right-click add watch > break on change in value (delete the watches later); or I prefer generally to insert the word STOP on a separate line just before the variables you are interested in then press F8 to execute code line by line, you can then hover over variables to see their values (just after you execute the line containing them), or inspect in the [locals window](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=locals+window+vba&oq=locals+window&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.2815j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: okay counting is wrong. Code read good from calendar cells, but values that code got aren't from right cells like every cell have delay. but this delay is random. There is no delay patern that I could follow

Comment: Delay? What does that mean ?

Comment: for example value that is in excel table on E5 is then showed up on B6 but it should be showed up like in excel table on E5

Comment: **Please** take care when tagging a question to use the correct tags. VBA and VB.NET are **not** the same language. The code you posted will not run in VBA and any answers you get will be the wrong syntax if people believe it should be VBA.